# Replace scrolling action by onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I used this snippet of code (had to adapt it) to autoload (think Twitter) new posts on my page when scrolling.

Since this is resource heavy for my server when a user scrolls fast, I want it to be activated when clicking on a button, lets say `<button id="load_more">Load more</button>`

Can anyone help me convert mine ? I can't get it to work... (plus eventually remove the busy indicator)

Here is the code I use for autoscroll :

```
<?php
 $maxPage = $this->Paginator->counter('%pages%');
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var lastX = 0;
 var currentX = 0;
 var page = 1;

 $(window).scroll(function () {
 if (page < <?php echo $maxPage;?>) {
  currentX = $(window).scrollTop();
 if (currentX - lastX > 150 * page) {
  lastX = currentX - 150;
  page++;
  $("#busy-indicator").fadeIn();
  $.get('<?php echo $this->Html->url('/users/getmore_timeline/'.$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')); ?>/page:' + page, function(data) {
  setTimeout(function(){
  $('#postList').append(data);
  var bi =  $("#busy-indicator");
       bi.stop(true, true);
       bi.fadeOut();
  }, 500);
 });
 }
 }
 });
 </script>
```

EDIT :

I tried (from memory)

```
<button onlick"LoadMore()">Load More</button>

<?php  
 $maxPage = $this->Paginator->counter('%pages%');  
 ?>  
 <script type="text/javascript">  

function LoadMore () {  
 if (page < <?php echo $maxPage;?>) {  
  page++;  
  $("#busy-indicator").fadeIn();  
  $.get('<?php echo $this->Html-  >url('/users/getmore_timeline/'.$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')); ?>/page:' + page, function(data) {
  setTimeout(function(){  
  $('#postList').append(data);  
  var bi =  $("#busy-indicator");  
       bi.stop(true, true);  
       bi.fadeOut();
  }, 500);
 });
 }
 };
 </script>
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? What did you try already?

Comment: @Odi

I tried

<button onlick"LoadMore()">Load More</button>

`<?php  
 $maxPage = $this->Paginator->counter('%pages%');  
 ?>  
 <script type="text/javascript">  
  
function LoadMore () {  
 if (page < <?php echo $maxPage;?>) {  
  page++;  
  $("#busy-indicator").fadeIn();  
  $.get('<?php echo $this->Html-  >url('/users/getmore_timeline/'.$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')); ?>/page:' + page, function(data) {
  setTimeout(function(){  
  $('#postList').append(data);  
  var bi =  $("#busy-indicator");  
       bi.stop(true, true);  
       bi.fadeOut();
  }, 500);
 });
 }
 };
 </script>`

Comment: Please update your question with this, it's very hard to read in the comments.

Comment: You're right I put it in the comments. keep in mind, the first code given, if copy pasted works ace with scrolling. I just want to replace the scrolling with clicking a button. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i missed something here, but if all you want is a button to call the function `LoadMore()`:

**HTML**

```
<button id="load_more">Load more</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('#load_more').on('click', function() {
    Loadmore()
})
```

*PS: about your `<button onlick"LoadMore()">Load More</button>`, you have a typo (very funny one :D), forgot a equal sign, and you should avoid using inline event handlers.*